# laravel form keep redirecting to same page

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5, eloquent

what is wrong with My Form here it keep redirecting to same page with having token in url any idea why this is happening

```
  <form action="{{url('variant')}}" method="POST">
                          @csrf

                          <div class="required field">
                    <div class="ui dropdown ui selection dropdown" style="max-width: 300px; margin-right: 17px;">
                          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                          <div class="default text">Soluation Body</div>
                          <div class="menu">
                          <div class="item" data-value="male">File Upload <span style="color: gray;">( zip )</span></div>
                          <div class="item" data-value="female">repository <span style="color: gray;">( github , gitlap ,...)</span></div>
                          <div class="item" data-value="female">List <span style="color: gray;">( futuers , basics )</span></div>
                          <div class="item" data-value="female">Code Editor <span style="color: gray;">( Code )</span></div>
                          <div class="item" data-value="male">Image <span style="color: gray;">( analysis || flow chart )</span></div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <button  type="submit" class="ui button">Add</button>
              </div>
              </form>
```

My Routes

```
     Route::post('variant', 'v1\AnswerController@variants')->name('variant.add');
```

My Controller

```
public function variants(Request $request)
{
    dd('No file');
}
```

Comment: where this url hits, send method code too

Comment: @BimalPrasadPandey i have updatedwith my route

Comment: send variants method too

Comment: @BimalPrasadPandey ok i updated please check

Comment: Try to `dd()` in the beginning of file `routes/web.php`. See what returns `request()` helper function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your form action to use a route instead:

```
<form action="{{ route('variant.add') }}">
```

Comment: Are you sure your route is reaching your controller correctly? Is it in the file structure of App\Http\Controllers\v1\AnswerController?

Comment: if not will get undefined route